# ArcPy JoinField Error 000574: Python is not installed

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins

I am new in coding. I am trying to add a field of to my attribute map using "Zonal statistics as Table" and "Join field" tools. For the last one I am using `arcpy.management.JoinField()` function, but get an error that Python is not installed. Trying to solve it, I repaired ArcGIS Pro in Windows Add/remove programs, played with the data and finally launched the tool directly in ArcGIS Pro (it worked perfectly).

How can I resolve the issue?

I attached a part of code below:

```py
import arcpy

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.nodata = "NONE"
arcpy.env.workspace=r"D:\Dissertation\Toolbox_Physical_Geomorphometry\script_data"

DEM=r"D:\Dissertation\Data\Mala_studena_dolina\aMSD_1m_big\LSVs_matlab\dem_18.asc"
polygon_layer = r"D:\Dissertation\Toolbox_Physical_Geomorphometry\test\Segmentation_2slope_2ktn_ss20.shp"

test_table=ZonalStatisticsAsTable(polygon_layer,
                                "FID",
                                DEM,
                                "D:/Dissertation/Toolbox_Physical_Geomorphometry/test/table_test.dbf",
                                "DATA", "MEAN")


#This code I copied from AGP when executed it there
arcpy.management.JoinField(
    in_data=polygon_layer,
    in_field="FID",
    join_table=table_test,
    join_field="OID",
    fields="MEAN",
    fm_option="NOT_USE_FM",
    field_mapping=None
)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dissertation\Toolbox_Physical_Geomorphometry\Segm_affinity.py", line 60, in <module>
    arcpy.management.JoinField(
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 9469, in JoinField
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 9466, in JoinField
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.JoinField_management(*gp_fixargs((in_data, in_field, join_table, join_field, fields, fm_option, field_mapping), True)))
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 512, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000574: Python is not installed.
ERROR 000574: Python is not installed.
Failed to execute (JoinField).
```

Comment: You may have an old clone of a previous AGP version in use.